# create new branch from other branch with sigle commit

Tags: git

I have 2 branches (2 different versions of project) in which were pushed some commits with passwords.
It is hard to find all these commits and also all commited files - it was like ~100 many commits before, and happend multiple times. Actually, 2 versions are released, so instead of cleaning history (which would be hard in this case i thinkg) i would like to just create new branches (one for version) which would have code from current version, but without all these commits (there were some 2k commits+) - i would like situation similar to new repo - like only one initial commit
How to do that ;) from console?

Comment: If you want to get rid of all history, why not just creating a new repo from the current codebase?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create the new branch:

```
$ git checkout -b new_branch
```

Then you can reset any number of commit like this (here 3):

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD~3
```

Alternatively, you can reset to a specific SHA1 hash:

```
$ git reset --soft 3171739
```

You can then check the log of commits to a branch:

```
$ git log
```

Note that none of your work will be destroyed but some files might be untracked, so you would have to add them afterwards. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Also note that if you go for the `reset --soft` route, one way to easily point to your first commit is `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD`